# Pattern like Bridge but can add primitive method?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, object-oriented-analysis

Suppose two abstract class:

```
  Log:
   property:timestamp;
   property:message;

  LogFormatter:
   (String *)formatlog:(Log)log;
```

This look like a bridge, `Log` behave like `Abstraction` and `LogFormatter` like `Implementor`. In my opinion, [bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern) can't add primitive method to `Implementor`. But I want to dynamic add property to log in the future, and use a subclass of `LogFormatter` to format it. This will break [`Liskov Substitution principle`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Anyone has any suggestion?

Comment: What about using composition for extended properties? The log could hold a set of `ExtendedLogProperty` or even just a `Map`. This would make it explicit in the contract that some properties are always present and part of the `Log`'s schema while other properties may be missing. At this point, there is no breaking of the LSP since you do not have to narrow the contract of `formatlog`.

Comment: Find a logging library for your technology and don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

If Log has properties timestamp and message, I think perhaps you mean it LogEntry.

The Bridge pattern is used when you want to decouple an abstraction from its
implementation so that the two can very independently. I think this is not 
your case. If you simply want to format a LogEntry as a String, just pass LogEntry as a parameter to a LogFormatter's method which returns a String.

If you want to dynamic add property to log in the future, and use a subclass of LogFormatter to format it. I would suggest Decorator or Strategy pattern, depending on what you 
really mean.

Edit:
The following pseudo code is an example how one can implement this with decorator to add property such as thread-ID to the log entry
    Log {
        timestamp
        message
        threadid
    }

```
interface LogFormatter {
    String format(Log);
}

// default implementation
DefaultLogFormatter implements LogFormatter {
    String format(Log) {
        return Log.getTimestamp() + Log.getMessage();
    }
}

// decorated with thread Id
ThreadIdLogFormatter implements LogFormatter {
    LogFormatter formatter; 
    ThreadIdLogFormatter(LogFormatter formatter) {
        this.formatter = formatter;
    }
    String format(Log) {
        String threadid = Log.getThreadId();
        return formatter.format() + threadid;
    }
}

LogFormatter formatterDefault = new DefaultLogFormatter();
LogFormatter formatterThreadId = new ThreadIdLogFormatter(formatterDefault);

Log log = new Log("message");
// 2016-11-28 09:22:07.055 INFO message 
String logEntryDefault = formatterDefault.format(log); 
// 2016-11-28 09:22:07.055 INFO message (Thread 11)
String logEntryThreadid = formatterThreadId.format(log);
```

Personally i would just define a abstract LogFormatter (or interface) and implement LogFormatter subclasses that format a Log entry into some form of text (line, xml, json, ...). Design Pattern is nice but perhaps not really necessary in this case.

Comment: I mean dynamic add property to log and subclass of LogFormatter, can you explain this more clear，thanks.